# how to split the string to get date only

Tags: c#, .net, string, split

I have got the  string like this below....

```
 string a = backup-2011-10-12_17-16-51.zip
```

How can i split the above string so that  only get  this part `2011-10-12`

For that I have tried this below  but i am not sure how to split the string exact like this

`2011-10-12`

```
  string[] getfiledate = a.Split(new[] { '.', '-','_' });
```

would any one pls help on how to split the one string .. .....

many thanks in advance..

Comment: If all you need to do is literally retrieve the date from that exact string, you could use `String.Substring(7, 10)`, which will grab the 10 consecutive characters starting at index 7. But I suspect you want a more-general solution. So: is the string always guaranteed to begin with `backup-`?

Comment: @djacobson yes string always starts with backup-...... change is only in date ....

Comment: Guess that's solved it, then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the string is always the same length, just use

```
a.Substring(7,10)
```

Answer (score 3):

A regex would be beneficial here.

```
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})
```

Comment: This is only the date part, unless the time part can have a 4-digit hour. Use like: `Regex.Match(a, "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}").Value`

Answer (score 2):

Here's my personal favorite:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("backup-2011-10-12_17-16-51.ip", "backup-yyyy-dd-MM_HH-mm-ss.ip", null);
```

This avoids substring calculations, but if you'll notice I had to remove the z from zip in your example because in timezone calculation z is the gmt offset... if you can avoid the z, then this works very nicely.

**EDIT For a more awesome answer**

use @ and \ to escape the z:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("backup-2011-10-12_17-16-51.zip", @"backup-yyyy-dd-MM_HH-mm-ss.\zip", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can expect that exact format all the time this will work

```
 string a = "backup-2011-10-12_17-16-51.zip";
 var temp = a.Replace("backup-", String.Empty);
 temp = temp.Substring(0, temp.IndexOf('_'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Very quick and dirty

```
string a = "backup-2011-10-12_17-16-51.zip";
string g = a.Replace("backup-", string.Empty);
string k = g.Remove(g.IndexOf("_"));
```